# Will not update the ID for a link on click

Tags: jquery

I have this function to create a request to another file to update the database:

```
$('#thumb-up').live('click', function() {
    $('#loading').show();

    $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/gallery/configurations/required/photo-thumbs.php',
            data: 'i=21&t=1',
            success: function() {
                                  $('#loading').hide();
                                  $(this).attr('id', 'thumbup-undo').text('Sluta gilla');
                                  $('#thumbup-count').load('/gallery/configurations/required/thumbup-count.php?i=21&t=1');
                                 }
    });
});

$('#thumbup-undo').click(function() {
    alert('das');
});
```

When I click on the link with the id `thumb-up` the text changes to "Sluta gilla" as expected. When I now have clicked on this link the ID for the same a tag will be changed from `thumb-up` to `thumbup-undo` and the alert "dsa" will appear. The problem here is that it does not appear! I don't even know if it changes to `thumbup-undo` but I expect that it does not.

You can try the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HbSjm/) (I have shortened the code to make the demo work properly).

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click','#thumb-up', function() {
    $('#loading').show();

    $.ajax({
            context: this,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/gallery/configurations/required/photo-thumbs.php',
            data: 'i=21&t=1',
            success: function() {
                                  $('#loading').hide();
                                  $(this).attr('id', 'thumbup-undo').text('Sluta gilla');
                                  $('#thumbup-count').load('/gallery/configurations/required/thumbup-count.php?i=21&t=1');
                                 }
    });
});

$('body').on('click','#thumbup-undo', function() {
    alert('das');
});
```

You have to use ON, since a "new" element is added to the dom after page load. remember .live is deprecated in the latest versions of Jquery

Comment: That even worked better than Tats_innit's solution! Many thanks! :D

Comment: You are welcome :). BTW, you can replace 'body' for a container that holds #thumb-up and #thumbup-undo. I used body bc I dont know if that's your case.

Answer (score 2):

**Pleas try this demo** http://jsfiddle.net/kxLzu/

I have use `.prop` and `.on` to bind the click and then on success I am telling the `foo` that this click exist.

Hope it helps :)

please note: `.live` is deprecated and `.on` should be used instead.

**code**

```
    $('#thumb-up').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                context: this,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function() {
                       $(this).prop('id', 'thumbup-undo').text('Sluta gilla');
                      foo();
                                     }
        });
    });

function foo(){
    $('#thumbup-undo').on('click', function() {
        alert('das');
    });
}
​
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer :) My problem has now been solved thanks to you. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, at the time of the assignment, `$("#thumbup-undo")` doesn't exist. It is only created later.

You can work around this by using `.live()`, as in [this updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbSjm/1/).

Comment: My God, am I seriously giving answers in jQuery? What is happening to me... Normally I'd suggest not using jQuery and present a full answer in raw JS... Also goes to show how much I reluctantly learn due to over-exposure on SO, LOL!

Comment: Remember .live is deprecated, you should recommend to use .on

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of
`.click()` (because that's the problem in your example: `#thumbup-undo` doesn't exist when you create the click handler)
and also instead of `.live()` (because `live()` is [deprecated in jquery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/)).